# How to order pictures in an HTML file

Tags: html, css, plotly

I am currently doing some plots with plotly in Javascript and HTML. I need to add next to the plotly graph 7 pictures.

So far I managed to add the fist picture on the RHS. This picture is 600x400 pixels. But now I want to display the same picture six times below the current one (obviously the picture should be 6 times scaled in order to fit in there).

Unfortunately I don't have any idea how to do it as I don't have any experience with HTML or CSS. I have tried already to create a grid which would contain the images and the graph but everything gets misaligned.

I add the code I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!-- Plotly.js -->
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<style>
img{
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  border : none;
  height: 50vh;
  align: "middle";
}
div.myDiv{
  position: relative;
  border : none;
  height: 50vh;
  align: "middle";
}
#hoverinfo{
  position: relative;
  border : none;
  background-color: white;
  }
</style>

</head>

<body bgcolor="white">
<div>
<img id="image_part" src="https://freedesignfile.com/upload/2017/05/Sunrise-tropical-island-beach-view-HD-picture-04.jpg">
<div id="myDiv"></div>
<div id="hoverinfo"></div>
</div>
<script>
var point_x = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var point_y = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var colors = [1,1,1,0,0,0];
var i;
var traces = [];

var max_x = Math.max(...point_x.map(Math.abs));
var max_y = Math.max(...point_y.map(Math.abs));
var max_range = Math.max(max_x,max_y);
max_range = max_range + 0.05*max_range;

for (i = 0; i < point_x.length; i++) { 
    var trace = {
            x: [point_x[i]],
            y: [point_y[i]],
            mode: 'markers',
            marker: {color:[colors[i]]},
            type: 'scatter'
    } 
    traces.push(trace);
}    

var myPlot = document.getElementById('myDiv'),
    hoverInfo = document.getElementById('hoverinfo')
data = traces;
    layout = { 
        hovermode:'closest',
    showlegend:true,
        title:'Hover on Points',
    xaxis: {
      range: [-max_range,max_range]
    }, 
    yaxis: { 
      range: [-max_range,max_range],
      scaleanchor: 'x'
    },
    aspectratio: {
      x: 1,
      y: 1
    },
    height: 1000,
    width: 1000
     };
Plotly.plot('myDiv', data, layout);    

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am also adding a picture explaining what I expect to get.
Thanks in advance!

[Description of what I expect to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RDHr.jpg)

EDIT 26/08/2019:

I managed to create the grid as Azzam Asghar suggested, but I am still unable to place the grid in the lower right corner as showed in the sketch I uploaded. I would really appreciate some help, this is my code now:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<style>
div.gallery-row {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;

}

div.gallery img {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;

}

div.desc {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: right;

}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.responsive {
  padding: 0 3px;
  width: 24.99999%;

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .responsive {
    width: 49.99999%;
    margin: 6px 0;

  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .responsive {
    width: 100%;

  }
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;

}

div.myDiv{
  position: relative;
  border : none;
  height: 50vh;
  float: left;
}

img{
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  border : none;
  height: 50vh;
}

</style>
</head>

<body bgcolor="white">

<img id="image_part" src="https://freedesignfile.com/upload/2017/05/Sunrise-tropical-island-beach-view-HD-picture-04.jpg">
<div class="gallery-row">
<div class="responsive">
  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="https://freedesignfile.com/upload/2017/05/Sunrise-tropical-island-beach-view-HD-picture-04.jpg">
      <img src="https://freedesignfile.com/upload/2017/05/Sunrise-tropical-island-beach-view-HD-picture-04.jpg" alt="Forest" width="150" height="100">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="responsive">
  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="https://freedesignfile.com/upload/2017/05/Sunrise-tropical-island-beach-view-HD-picture-04.jpg">
      <img src="https://freedesignfile.com/upload/2017/05/Sunrise-tropical-island-beach-view-HD-picture-04.jpg" alt="Northern Lights" width="150" height="100">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="responsive">
  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="https://freedesignfile.com/upload/2017/05/Sunrise-tropical-island-beach-view-HD-picture-04.jpg">
      <img src="https://freedesignfile.com/upload/2017/05/Sunrise-tropical-island-beach-view-HD-picture-04.jpg" alt="Mountains" width="150" height="100">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="gallery-row">
<div class="responsive">
  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="https://freedesignfile.com/upload/2017/05/Sunrise-tropical-island-beach-view-HD-picture-04.jpg">
      <img src="https://freedesignfile.com/upload/2017/05/Sunrise-tropical-island-beach-view-HD-picture-04.jpg" alt="Forest" width="150" height="100">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="responsive">
  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="https://freedesignfile.com/upload/2017/05/Sunrise-tropical-island-beach-view-HD-picture-04.jpg">
      <img src="https://freedesignfile.com/upload/2017/05/Sunrise-tropical-island-beach-view-HD-picture-04.jpg" alt="Northern Lights" width="150" height="100">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="responsive">
  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="https://freedesignfile.com/upload/2017/05/Sunrise-tropical-island-beach-view-HD-picture-04.jpg">
      <img src="https://freedesignfile.com/upload/2017/05/Sunrise-tropical-island-beach-view-HD-picture-04.jpg" alt="Mountains" width="150" height="100">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="myDiv"></div>

<script>

var point_x = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var point_y = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var colors = [1,1,1,0,0,0];
var i;
var traces = [];

var max_x = Math.max(...point_x.map(Math.abs));
var max_y = Math.max(...point_y.map(Math.abs));
var max_range = Math.max(max_x,max_y);
max_range = max_range + 0.05*max_range;

for (i = 0; i < point_x.length; i++) { 
    var trace = {
            x: [point_x[i]],
            y: [point_y[i]],
            mode: 'markers',
            marker: {color:[colors[i]]},
            type: 'scatter'
    } 
    traces.push(trace);
}    

var myPlot = document.getElementById('myDiv'),
    hoverInfo = document.getElementById('hoverinfo');
var data = traces;
var layout = { 
        hovermode:'closest',
    showlegend:true,
        title:'Hover on Points',
    xaxis: {
      range: [-max_range,max_range]
    }, 
    yaxis: { 
      range: [-max_range,max_range],
      scaleanchor: 'x'
    },
    aspectratio: {
      x: 1,
      y: 1
    },
    height: 1000,
    width: 1000
     };
Plotly.plot('myDiv', data, layout);   




</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don’t get what you are actually trying to ask here. Is this about drawing the graphs with JS? Or simply about image placement within a page, completely independent of the JS part?

Comment: @misorude Sorry if I was not clear enough. Yes the question is about the image placement within the page, independent of the JS part like you said.

Answer (score 0):

How about modifying w3 example of responsive [example](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_image_gallery_responsive) according to your needs.
Here is a [blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-c4hasn).

So what you need to do is fix height and width of the image(although there are ways you won't have to do this). Than simply do control the width for smaller screens using css media queries.

Comment: I made an edit to the original post, I managed to add the grid you suggested but I am still having trouble ordering the grid, the big picture and the plot as show in the sketch I uploaded.